# java - how to connect client and server on lan?

Tags: java, server, client

This is a (slightly) modified version of thenewboston's java instant messenger program.

However there seems to be a problem.
If i run both server and client on the same device it's working normal, but if client is on another pc (local) it fails to connect.

P.S i have very little knowledge about networking, streams and sockets so please keep that in mind.

EDIT : Everything is fixed , was using the wrong ip address from client side !

```
//SERVER
public class Server {

private JFrame                 frame;
private JTextField             userText;
private JTextArea              textArea;
private ObjectOutputStream     output;
private ObjectInputStream      input;
private ServerSocket           server;
private Socket                 connection;
private boolean                userTerminatedConnection = false;
private static final int PORT = 6789;
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Server window = new Server();
     window.frame.setVisible(true);
     window.startServer();
}


public Server() {
    initialize();
}

private void initialize() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1){}
    frame = new JFrame("SERVER");
    frame.setBounds(300, 300, 318, 338);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    userText = new JTextField();
    frame.getContentPane().add(userText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    userText.setEditable(false);
    userText.setColumns(10);
    userText.addActionListener(new
            ActionListener(){
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    sendMessage(arg0.getActionCommand());
                    userText.setText(null);


                }



    }
            );

    textArea = new JTextArea();
    textArea.setEditable(false);
    textArea.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
}

public void startServer(){
    try{
        server = new ServerSocket(PORT);
        System.out.println(InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress());
        while(true){
            try{
                waitForConnection();
                setupStreams();
                whileChatting();
            }catch(EOFException e){
                showMessage("\nSERVER TERMINATED CONNECTION");
            }finally{
                closeAll();
            }
        }
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}





private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
    String message ="You are now connected !";
    sendMessage(message);
    ableToType(true);
    do{
        try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n"+message);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            showMessage("\n UNRECOGNISED OBJECT");
        }catch(SocketException ex){
            userTerminatedConnection = true;
        }
    }while(!message.endsWith("ENDCONN") && !userTerminatedConnection);
    userTerminatedConnection = false;
}


private void setupStreams() throws IOException{
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
}


private void waitForConnection() throws IOException {
  showMessage("Waiting for connection...\n");
  connection = server.accept();
  showMessage("Now connected to "+connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());
}

private void closeAll() {
    showMessage("\nClosing connection \n");
    ableToType(false);
    try{
        input.close();
        output.close();
        connection.close();
    }catch(IOException e){

    }
}

private void ableToType(final boolean b) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    userText.setEditable(b);
                }
            }
    );
}


private void sendMessage(String string) {
    try{
        output.writeObject("SERVER - "+string);
        output.flush();
        showMessage("\nSERVER - "+string);
    }catch(IOException e){
        textArea.append("\nCANT SEND");
    }

}


private void showMessage(final String string) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    textArea.append(string);
                }
            }
    );

}

 }




 //CLIENT



 public class Client {

private JFrame                frame;
private JTextField            userText;
private JTextArea             chatBox;
private ObjectOutputStream    output;
private ObjectInputStream     input;
private String                message;
private String                serverIP;
private Socket                connection;
private boolean               isConnected = false;
private String                clientName = "CLIENT";

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     Client window = new Client();
     window.frame.setVisible(true);
     window.clientName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter client nickname");
     String ipEntered = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Enter the ip address to establish connection !");

     if(ipEntered.equals("localhost")||ipEntered.equals("")){
         ipEntered = "127.0.0.1";
     }

     if(window.clientName.equals("")){
         window.clientName = "CLIENT";
     }

     if(window.clientName.toCharArray().length > 15){
         window.clientName = "CLIENT";
     }

     window.setHostIp(ipEntered);
     window.startClient();
}


public Client() {
    initialize();
}

private void setHostIp(String host){
    serverIP = host;
}
private void initialize() {
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
    }catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException e1){}
    frame = new JFrame("Client");
    frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) {
            if(isConnected)
            closeAll();
        }
    });
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 318, 338);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    chatBox = new JTextArea();
    chatBox.setFont(new Font("Monospaced", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(chatBox), BorderLayout.CENTER);

    userText = new JTextField();
    userText.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 11));
    userText.setEditable(false);
    frame.getContentPane().add(userText, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    userText.setColumns(10);
    userText.addActionListener(
         new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                sendData(arg0.getActionCommand());
                userText.setText("");
            }



         }
    );

}
private void startClient() throws IOException{
    try{
        connectToServer();
        setupStreams();
        whileChatting();
        isConnected = true;
    }catch(EOFException ex){
        showMessage("\nClient terminated connection");
    }finally{
        if(isConnected)
        closeAll();
        else
            System.exit(0);
    }
}


private void connectToServer() throws IOException{
    showMessage("\nAttempting connection");
    connection = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(serverIP),6789);
    showMessage("\nConnected to :"+connection.getInetAddress().getHostName());

}

private void setupStreams() throws IOException {
    output = new ObjectOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
    output.flush();
    input = new ObjectInputStream(connection.getInputStream()); 
}

private void whileChatting() throws IOException{
    ableToType(true);
    do{
        try{
            message = (String) input.readObject();
            showMessage("\n"+message);
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            showMessage("UNRECOGNISED OBJECT");
        }
    }while(!message.equals("SERVER - ENDCONN"));
}

private void closeAll() {
    showMessage("\nClosing stuff");
    ableToType(false);
    try{
        output.close();
        input.close();
        connection.close();
    }catch(IOException e){

    }
    System.exit(0);
}



private void sendData(String mess) {
    try{
        output.writeObject(clientName+" - "+mess);
        showMessage("\n"+clientName+" - "+mess);
    }catch(IOException e){
        chatBox.append("\nSomething went wrong");
    }

}
private void showMessage(String string) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    chatBox.append(string);
                }
            }
    );

}
private void ableToType(final boolean b) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(
            new Runnable(){
                public void run(){
                    userText.setEditable(b);
                }
            }
    );
}

 }
```

Comment: Is port 6789 blocked to external connections. Start the server on whichever machine and then from a command prompt run "nestat -an" and share the results.

Comment: since you are not specifying bind address explicitly, the server will bind to all available network interfaces i.e it will be capable of remote access by default

Comment: netstat -an gave me the following result for port 6789: LISTENING

Comment: @monish how do i do that ? as i said im not very experienced in networking.

Comment: @Vlad i dont think you need to do anything to bind the server to remote interface, it should already be bound. You can verify if the server is listening on remote interface by running netstat command. If you wish to explicity bind the server to a specific interface (local / remote) you can do so by this constructor ServerSocket(int port, InetAddress bindAddr)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this method: `waitForConnection();`, eventually blocks your entire flow so that it can wait for incoming connections and handle them when they come.

What you would need to do, would be to make sure that waiting and handling of incoming connections is done on seperate threads so as to ensure that you are not blocking your current application.

EDIT:
The [`.accept()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#accept()) method blocks your main thread until a new connection arrives. What is usually done (depending on the type of server you are building) is that the `.accept` part is done in a seperate thread. You would need this so that waiting is done on another thread and that you do not block your main one.

Now, there are scenarios were coming up with a response can take time. To go around this, the construction and transmission of a response is also done in a seperate thread so as to now affect new requests.

If this is not a requirement (you can wait a few seconds to get a response back, or if you can construct a response relatively fast, or you will have a relatively low amount of clients) then you can do without the creation of a new thread to cater for incoming requests, and create just one which waits for incoming connections.

Comment: You mean i should put the entire waitForConnection() method into a thread ? or make separate methods to both wait and handle connections ?

Comment: In my case i dont really need fast response , nor multiple clients, but the issue is that when i put the contents of waitForConnection() method into a thread, the program returns an error, probably because its trying to connect before a connection was established.

Comment: @Vlad: Without the error it is difficult to tell, but yes, you would need to allow enough time for the server to load up.

Comment: I managed to set the server up without errors, will test it later, thank you !